# how to get href value using JS?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the value of an href using java script and then pass it to another file of php, I did the code of JS and the value return is correct, but I dont know how to get the value and pass it, thank in advance.
I am new in JS

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('div#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr('href');
    var p=n.slice(5,6); 
    alert(p);

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: should use ajax. or you can put it in a hidden input in a form and submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use AJAX to pass it PHP, here's a sample AJAX call to `test.php` passing your value:

```
$('div#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr('href');
    var p=n.slice(5,6); 
    alert(p);

    //AJAX TIME
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test.php'
        data: {value : p}
        success: function(data) {
            //do something with response 'data'
        }
    });
});
```

And in your PHP, get the passed in data

```
$data = $_POST['value'];
```