# Why does my script not pass a value to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the value of an href using java script and then pass it to another file of php, I did the code of JS and some friend add J query to it, in order to pass the value to the test.php file, but I don't why it is not working.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('div#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr('href');
    var p=n.slice(5,6); 
    alert(p);
     $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test.php'
        data: {value : p}
        success: function(data) {
            //do something with response 'data'
        }

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Whats your console say about the request, specifically, the Network tab.

Comment: How is it "not working"? Are you getting unexpected output? Are you getting no output at all? Are there errors, and if so, what are they? Have you looked at the console?

Comment: in php file I wrote: $data = $_POST['value']; and echo the data

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  I'm guessing you can't access the value in php? Any errors messages?  If so, what are they? Also, your related php would be useful to see . . .

Comment: @user2784585 Is this all your code or is `//do something with response 'data'` a placeholder for actual code?

Comment: What do you do in your success function? It won't display the response unless you do something with it.

Comment: @NullUserException -- It's from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899884/how-to-get-href-value-using-js/18899949#18899949

Comment: Don't you need commas when building a set in javascript? `{url: 'test.php', data: {value : p}, etc..}` I'm no expert..

Comment: Assuming you fix the numerous syntax errors in your code, it still won't display anything, because you're not doing anything with the response text. JS doesn't know what you want to do with the response, you have to code that in. `//do something with response 'data'` isn't going to magically display text.

Comment: inside //do something with response 'data' what should i write to pass value into test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a final `});` (and a few commas) in your code example.  It should look like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('div#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
        var n = $(this).attr('href');
        var p = n.slice(5, 6);
        alert(p);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {value : p},
            success: function(data) {
                // Do something with response 'data'
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: that's right now, but some friend comment that I should write something in place of //Do something with response 'data'.
what should I write to pass value to test.php

Comment: You don't; the ajax request already did that. Your test.php will do something with the value you sent it, and then it will return something and store that into the data value.

Comment: I get value like : $data = $_POST['value'];
and then pass it to my sql query in where class and in my table the value is also available but it is not showing anything and no error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a set in javascript, the key/value pairs need commas:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('div#tabs ul li a').click(function() {
    var n = $(this).attr('href');
    var p=n.slice(5,6); 
    alert(p);
     $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {value : p},
        success: function(data) {
            //do something with response 'data'
        }

});
});
});
</script>
```